# Monit will not stop script with kill command

Tags: passenger, monit

I am using monit to monitor several process. These process include passenger instances and a daemon I wrote to generate pidfiles for the passenger instance. Monit will start these process no problem. It will not stop them. The following is the Monit config for the daemon:

```
check process passenger_monitor with pidfile <%= passenger_monitor_pid %>
   group <%= application %>
   start program = "/bin/su - rails_apps -c 'source /home/rails_apps/.rvm/scripts/rvm; /home/rails_apps/passenger_monitor.rb'"
   stop program = "/bin/kill `/bin/cat <%= passenger_monitor_pid %>`"
```

It is a erb template that is generated via capistrano. If I run the stop command via a terminal as root with a minimal environment then it works, but when I request that Monit stops the process i get the following error:

```
[ADT Sep 17 10:38:31] error    : 'passenger_monitor' failed to stop
```

I have tried everything I can think of. I cannot find or generate any logs of the output of the stop command.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I have the same issue when trying to stop a service using

```
stop program = "/bin/kill `/bin/cat /var/run/pusher.pid`"
```

You can turn on the `-Iv` flag to see the debug output:

```
monit -Iv
```

Or you can manually validate while monit is running in the background:

```
monit validate
```

They both show

```
'api-pusher-service' stop: /bin/kill
kill: can't find process "`/bin/cat"
kill: can't find process "/var/run/pusher.pid`"
```

This fixes the problem for me

```
stop program = "/bin/bash -c '/bin/kill `/bin/cat /var/run/pusher.pid`'"
```